# how to interpolate a fluctuated vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two arrays

```
x = [0    9.8312   77.1256  117.9810   99.9979];
y = [0    2.7545    4.0433    5.3763    5.0504];
figure; plot(x, y)
```

[image]

I want to make more samples of `x` and `y` then I interpolated both arrays. I tried this code

```
xi =min(x):.1:max(x);
yi = interp1(x,y,xi);
figure; plot(xi, yi)
```

[image]

but the trajectory is not same as previous plot. Its because the `xi` is not fluctuating same as `x`. How should I interpolate both arrays with same trajectory as original one?

Comment: The problem is that your query points are monotonically increasing, and that's what you use for both your interpolation and your plotting result. I'm not sure MATLAB can cope with this kind of multi-valuedness on x-coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue because when interpolating, MATLAB is going to ignore the *order* that you feed in the points and instead just sort them based upon their x location.

Rather than interpolating in x/y coordinates, you can instead use a parameter which represents the cumulative arc length of the line segments and use *that* to interpolate both the x and y coordinates. This will provide you with an interpolant that respects the order and guarantees monotonicity even for multiple values at the same x coordinate.

```
% Compute the distance between all points.
distances = sqrt(diff(x).^2 + diff(y).^2);

% Compute the cumulative arclength
t = cumsum([0 distances]);

% Determine the arclengths to interpolate at
tt = linspace(t(1), t(end), 1000);

% Now interpolate x and y at these locations
xi = interp1(t, x, tt);
yi = interp1(t, y, tt);
```