# Monotonicty with the interp1 function

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Sometimes when I use the `interp1` function in MATLAB, it throws an error saying my vectors need to be monotonically increasing, and other times it doesn't.

For example, let's say I have 3 vectors.

```
A = [286, 295, 298, 301, 304, 308, 310, 324, 330, 335];   

B = [31000, 30950, 30875, 30775, 30650, 30500, 30425, 29900, 29675, 29450];  

C = [290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299];
```

And I want to run

```
D = interp1(A,B,C);
```

This function will return successfully even though `B` is not monotonically increasing. Does the monotonicity only apply to the first and third vectors passing into the equation?

Answer (score 2):

#### What the error message *actually* means

The error is actually a little mis-leading in this case and is caused by all values in `A` not being unique (not strictly monotonic). The error (which is less useful) actually propagates up from `griddedInterpolant` which is used by many interpolation functions and therefore has a generic error message.

#### Why it only applies to some inputs

With `interp1` you are essentially attempting to construct an estimate of a function `f(x)` using `x` locations provided by the user as well as their corresponding values (`f(x)`). In your example, `A` contains the location of each data point (`x`) and `B` contains the values of your function at each of those points (`f(x)`).  It is only necessary that the *locations* (values in `A`) are unique so that you don't have multiple values in `B` for the same value of `A`. If you did, `interp1` doesn't know how to cope with that.

The ordering of `A` (the monotonically **increasing** part of the error) doesn't matter because `interp1` will automatically sort `A` to be increasing (it also re-arranges `B` so that the values still correspond to `A`).*

`C` is simply the locations at which you want to *sample* the interpolant. You can request the value of the function at the same point a million times with no issue. `interp1` will simply return the corresponding value for each location in `C` so there are no constraints on the values or ordering of `C`.

```
A = [1 3 2];        % Not monotically increasing but DOES need to be unique values

B = [1 2 1];        % Can have any value and can repeat values but each
                    % value corresponds with each element in A

C = [3 3 1 1 2 2];  % Can be any order and can repeat values

% ERROR FREE!
interp1(A, B, C)
%     2     2     1     1     1     1
```

*If you *do* want the ordering of your `A` and `B` points to be respected, then you'll want to parameterize your input data in a different way as suggested in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363651/how-to-interpolate-a-fluctuated-vector-in-matlab/41364427#41364427)